# Rails 3.2.3 Guard outside of bundler error instead of Failures

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, guard

I'm running Rails 3.2.3 on Windows, and working on this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had/.  When I run 'guard'(time 4:34) I get the following error instead of seeing Failures.  I have already removed removed minitest from my gemfile.  Any suggestions?

```
     C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Sites\tasks>guard
     ←[0m
     Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are running
     `guard` outside of Bundler. If this is your intent, feel free to ignore this
     message. Otherwise, consider using `bundle exec guard` to ensure your
     dependencies are loaded correctly.
     (You can run `guard` with --no-bundler-warning to get rid of this message.)
     ←[0m
     ←[0mGuard could not detect any of the supported notification libraries.←[0m
     ←[0mGuard is now watching at 'C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Sites/tasks'←[0m
     ←[0mGuard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!←[0m
     ←[0m←[0mRunning all specs←[0m
     ansi: 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows
     gem install minitest
     C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:23:in `<top
     (required)>': MiniTest v1.6.0 is out of date. (RuntimeError)
     `gem install minitest` and add `gem 'minitest' to you test helper.
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13:in `r
     equire'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13:in `<
     top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runti
     me.rb:68:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runti
     me.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runti
     me.rb:66:in `each'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runti
     me.rb:66:in `block in require'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runti
     me.rb:55:in `each'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runti
     me.rb:55:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:11
     9:in `require'
     from C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Sites/tasks/config/application.rb:13:in `
     <top (required)>'
     from C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Sites/tasks/config/environment.rb:2:in `r
     equire'
     from C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Sites/tasks/config/environment.rb:2:in `<
     top (required)>'
     from C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Sites/tasks/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `req
     uire'
     from C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Sites/tasks/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<to
     p (required)>'
     from C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Sites/tasks/spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:1
     :in `require'
     from C:/Users/Steven/Documents/Sites/tasks/spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:1
     :in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.0/lib/rspec/cor
     e/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.0/lib/rspec/cor
     e/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.0/lib/rspec/cor
     e/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.0/lib/rspec/cor
     e/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.0/lib/rspec/cor
     e/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.0/lib/rspec/cor
     e/runner.rb:69:in `run'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.0/lib/rspec/cor
     e/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
     > C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.4.7/lib/listen/adapters/windows.r
     b:42:in `join': Interrupt
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.4.7/lib/listen/adapter
     s/windows.rb:42:in `stop'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-0.4.7/lib/listen/listene
     r.rb:55:in `stop'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.2.3/lib/guard.rb:169:in
     `stop'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.2.3/lib/guard/cli.rb:10
     2:in `rescue in start'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.2.3/lib/guard/cli.rb:99
     :in `start'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/task.rb:27
     :in `run'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/invocation
     .rb:120:in `invoke_task'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor.rb:275:in
     `dispatch'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/base.rb:40
     8:in `start'
     from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.2.3/bin/guard:6:in `<to
     p (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby192/bin/guard:23:in `load'
     from C:/Ruby192/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by going into my Ruby directory and deleting the minitest.rb file.  I then went to the turn.rb file and commented out the following:

```
require 'turn/minitest'
```

Hope this helps!